# Where can I view CSS warnings in Chrome32's console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Where can I view CSS warnings in Chrome32's console?

I can find it in Chrome31's console if I check "CSS" in the filter menu. However, I can not find it in the same place of Chrome32's console.

Answer (score 0):

This was removed November 2013 while they rework their console filtering. No word yet on when/if it will be back.

**Related threads:**

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=309982
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244776